# Why is my ajax php file variables undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to learn jQuery ajax the function seems to be working properly so says browser web developer tools but the values aren't pulled through to the php file(url) that I have here's my simple code.

This is the HTML anf jQuery File

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Working with PHP and jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="#myForm">
    <p>
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <input  type="text" name="Name">
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Are you male
        <input type="checkbox" name="IsMale">
        </label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Enter your email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="Email">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </p>
    </form>

    <div id="loadResult"></div>

    <script>
    $(function() { 
        $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/form1.php',
                type: 'POST',               
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success: function(result) { 
                    console.log(result); $('#loadResult').html(result); 
                },
                error: function(badresult){ alert("ajax error function hit"); console.log(badresult); }             
            });         
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the php file

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST['Name'];
    $isMale = $_POST['IsMale'];
    $email = $_POST['Email'];

    echo "Name is $name, are you a male? $isMale. Your email address is $email";
?>
```

I am using the jquery serialize function but don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the console or in `#loadResult`?

Comment: What do you see in developers console?

Comment: I get the same output in the console and in the div that I'm appending to, telling me "notice undefined" for the 3 php variables that I have declared in my php file

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what you're getting is this line blowing up

```
$isMale = $_POST['IsMale'];
```

And in your HTML we see

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsMale">
```

Checkboxes, when they are not checked, are not successful, meaning they won't show up in `$_POST`. From the [jQuery serialize manual](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. 
> *snip*
>   Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked

So you need to check that it was submitted

```
$isMale = (isset($_POST['IsMale'])) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Comment: Thanks but it's giving me the same errors for my other two inputs although they aren't checkboxes